# Open URL using browser alongwith data

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to open the browser using python.

I saw the Webbrowser module , which helps me fire a URL with a browser.

But i wanted to send a  POST request by opening a browser.

The requests Module helps me to create a POST request alongwith the headers & Data .

Can i send the same by opening a browser tab or window ?

Comment: Tell me about functionality you need. Javascript capabilities? Controls? From the sounds of it, you can use urllib for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Selenium for Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

For example :

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.quit()
```

That will launch a Firefox browser and get the URL you passed to the driver. It's up to you to find out how you can perform what you want to do now ;)

Comment: great suggestion, but please fix example given :) you import Keys and never use it.  You should also call driver.quit() rather than close().

Comment: Hey..I tried to install selenium , but am not able to do so, checked out some post too..still no luck. Can you guys give me a heads up doing so. Pip fails to install selenium. Downloaded the Selenium tar from python website, it installs but doesnt resolve imports.

Comment: Depends on what version of python you're using. I had no problem installing selenium with pip.

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html Did you try to follow this tutorial ?